# mysql utf8 turkish characters not correct recognized

Tags: mysql

In mysql utf8 coded turkish data i can't search "İ" and "ı". when i search its giving result contains "Y" or "y". Because in latin1 "İ" displaying as "Ý" and "ı" as "ý".

in latin1 data i was used latin1_general_ci for correct result. but there is not alternative collation for utf8. its already utf8_general_ci.

is there any other people have some problems or do you have a solution.

thanks.

i have tried stackoverflow search engine to for this problem. if its have mysql and utf8 then my work true. try search "alİ" and "ali". both search give another result. but both same in turkish. the "İ" is capital i and capital "I" is "ı" in turkish.

there is a solution but not fully.

i you use utf8_turkish_ci then the result give "İ" but also "Y".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is temporary solved. i you use all collations uf8_turkish_ci you can get correct result. but i am wondering why i have to use turkish_ci.

try collate all columns utf8_turkish_ci, tables utf8_turkish_ci, and database too.

good luck